# Grails unique test fails after interchanging attribute values

Tags: grails, grails-validation

Hello I am trying to implement a simple translation list, meaning I have a values and translations to this values.

[Edit:] As this is part of my user interface and values and translations shall be exportable via xml, using the i18n files seams quite inconvinient for this proposition. Thats why I decided to store them in a database.

I have one domain class for a value:

```
class Value {
    String label
    static hasMany = [ translations: Translation ]
}
```

and one for translations with a unique constraint to ensure that for one value there must'nt be more than one translation for a specific language:

```
class Translation {
    String value
    Language language

    static belongsTo = [ value: Value ]

    static constraints = {
        language(unique: 'value')
    }
}
```

My problem occures after interchanging two translation languages for the same value.
Example:

```
value.translations.each() { translation ->
    println "${value.label} in ${translation.language.label} is ${translation.value}"
}

// process updates...

value.translations.each() { translation ->
    println "${value.label} in ${translation.language.label} is ${translation.value}"
}

// validate...
```

prints out

```
Comedy in german: Comedy
Comedy in english: Komödie   

Comedy in english: Comedy
Comedy in german: Komödie
```

so the unique constraint is not violated before and after the update, but anyhow I get an unique constraint failure while saving.
Another strange thing is, that I only get this error when I execute the each() loop on value. If I don't inspect the contents, the validation passes and the save(flush:true) method returns true, but the values will not be changed in the database.

[Edit:] I believe that the problem is on database level when only one value is altered and the other isn't, because exactly in that state the constraint is violated. If the changes would be executed as a transaction instead and the constraints would not be checked during this intermediate step this could be avoided. (this might be the thing, i am looking for)

Another way to avoid this would be to delete and recreate every edited bean but I was hoping that there might be a more convenient way to do this.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why arent you using translation files like the rest of the world?

Comment: Its a minimalistic example of my problem and I think an analogical example is easy to find. One Problem is, that the creation of values and translations is part of my user interface and altering the i18n files for this proposition seams quite unconvinient.

Comment: Is the unique constraint really necessary? have you tried pessimistic locking?

Comment: As far as I know locking in general only ensures, that the "I" in the "ACID"-principles is fulfilled, meaning that there must be a way of handling the case when two actors edit the same recoure at a time. 
I'm afraid i cant see the coherence to this case, as the problem is not that I am altering two values at a time, but that the values with the unique constraints interchange.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint is checked when an implicit or explicit `flush()` happens. At that moment, GORM checks if there exists another such a value **in a database**. So, if one instance is already `flush()`ed and another is not yet, you'll get a constraint violation.

Try not to `flush()` till the end of transaction - remove `flush: true` parameter or even set it to `flush: false`. At the end of transaction both changes should apply.

There's a caveat in Grails, JFYTK: it does an implicit `flush()` when executing a `Criteria`, so don't be too surprised about Hibernate errors when you didn't intend to `flush()` yet.